# Do I need to activate Windows 8 if I used it before?

Tags: windows-8, reinstall, windows-activation

I recently installed Linux on a laptop with preinstalled Windows 8 and I'd like to start using Windows again. I used to use it before. Will I need to buy Windows 8 again if I get the official ISO file from the Windows website?

Comment: The Windows installation environement will automatically detect your license key.  Windows will activate (again) automatically.  If it doesn't then manual activation might be required, but what you are attempting to do, does not require you to purchase another WIndows license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I already used it before, do i need to buy Windows 8 again, if i get
>   the official ISO file from the Windows website?

The Windows installation environment will automatically detect your Windows 8 OEM license which is stored on the ACPI table on your laptop's motherboard.  Since finding a Windows 8 ISO is difficult, I would suggest just using the `Microsoft Windows and Office ISO Download Tool` by HeliDoc.net.

[image]

After you have the tool installed and the ISO downloaded create the installation disk and install Windows 8.