# Where to download Windows OS (7, 8.1, 10)?

Tags: windows

Where can I find a download link for a Microsoft Windows 7, 8.1 or 10 ISO?

Comment: Just Google Windows 7 ISO, etc. For Windows 10 Google Windows Media Creation Tool

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/1151443/do-i-need-to-activate-windows-8-if-i-used-it-before/1151469#1151469

Answer (score 0):

Check this website - https://heidoc.net

You could use their tool - https://www.heidoc.net/php/Windows%20ISO%20Downloader.exe - every download link I have tried so far has been from a Microsoft link address.

The website also has download links for Microsoft Office as well, 2007 - 2016 and 365

Comment: This is just a near duplicate of my answer to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/1151443/do-i-need-to-activate-windows-8-if-i-used-it-before/1151469#1151469