# Windows 7 Home Premium missing administrator account

Tags: windows-7, administrator

A computer that doesn't get used much needed updates the other day but it seems to be missing an admin account. I tried to activate it through cmd but since the one account on there is a standard user, it does not have the privileges to execute the commands to do this. I've also tried starting the pc in safe mode with cmd and it pulls up a standard user cmd every time. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer).  The answer I wrote still works for Windows 7, all you need is a Windows 7 ISO, which I explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062) how to get.  Otherwise the steps are **exactly** the same.

Comment: [Microsoft Windows and Office ISO Download Tool](https://superuser.com/questions/1151443/do-i-need-to-activate-windows-8-if-i-used-it-before/1151469#1151469) is a faster way to download the Windows 7 ISO.

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be to boot with something like Offline NT Password & Registry Editor, it will allow you to easily enable the built-in Administrator account or even (better) to elevate the current standard user to be a normal admin. http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html

Answer (score 1):

Run the cmd as administrator by searching cmd then right clicking it and then "run as administrator". Then you can execute `net user administrator /active:yes`

Comment: Agreed, most likely it was disabled for security

Comment: This does not work as there is no administrator. When I do this the Yes/No Box pops up and yes is grayed out. It does not even let me enter a password.

Comment: Try option 2, 3 or 4 from here. It will work with Windows 7 as well https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9650-built-administrator-account-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html

Comment: @user732204 - So enable the built-in Administrator.  This assume you have the required authorization to enable the built-in Administrator.

Comment: @Ramhound Sometimes.  By default, the admin account is hidden in Windows 7 and later but the default account that is created is usually admin account.

Comment: There is no admin account to activate the hidden admin. I cannot elevate anything to admin privileges.

Comment: @user732204 - You don't need an Administrator account to activate the built-in Administrator account which is disabled by default.  *The built-in Administrator account is disabled by default.*

Comment: You do though. You need admin to run that command.