# Create A Bootable Disc Or USB From Preinstalled Windows 7 In Laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, laptop, usb

I have an HP laptop with preinstalled Windows 7. I have another PC where I want to install Windows 7.

I want to know how to create a bootable disc or flash drive from the laptop to install the Windows 7 to the PC.

I have the product key from the laptop.

Is this possible?

Comment: *I have another PC where I want to install Windows 7.* - You do understand that your OEM license cannot be transferred to this new pc right?  *Is this possible?* - It is absolutely trivial, to install Windows 7 on a PC, but what you want to do, will simply result in an unlicensed installation of Windows 7

Comment: See my answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062). Possible duplicate of [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

Comment: @Ramhound Does the other thread seem anywhere near to this? :) It's about where to download Windows 7 (already have the serial key). I am asking how to create a bootable disc out of the Windows 7 installed on my laptop.

Comment: It absolutely does.  Read my answer to that question I got into detail on how to make an ISO but you dot have a key you can use actual your OEM cannot be translated to another pc

Comment: So, it is not possible, right? Even if I use the System Repair Disc?

Comment: You cannot install your current license on another pc your welcome to download an ISO and install an unlicensed install of Windows 7 though

Comment: I have been trying to insert the JS code into the console, it's saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at <anonymous>:3:23`. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Failing the JavaScript method, use [Microsoft Windows and Office ISO Download Tool](https://superuser.com/questions/1151443/do-i-need-to-activate-windows-8-if-i-used-it-before/1151469#1151469), less technical solution

Comment: Even this is not working. :)

Comment: Works for me.  Be more specific then "not working"

Comment: I selected Windows 7 Professional SP1 and selected "English". It's prompting "encountered a problem processing your request".

Comment: If you don't find another solution you could try a linux tool like clonezilla to copy the contents of the entire harddisk over to the hdd of the other computer. i.e. connect the other hdd to your win 7 computer, copy the hdd and then place it back into the new computer. If it doesn't boot you can use the system repair disc to fix it. example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gr4T47_rkLw

Answer (score 0):

You can just download Windows from Microsoft.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7

Comment: The link in question only works for retail licenses, the author, clearly has an OEM license

Comment: Please delete that comment it's possible to download directly from Microsoft third-party isn't required and unhelpful

Answer (score -2):

1. Create or Download an ISO for the Windows Installation Media
2. Create Your Installation USB Drive with the Windows USB/DVD Download Tool

Comment: There is already a duplicate question with an answer that basically says this, the difference, is this answer doesn't provide any substantial details how to download a Windows 7 ISO.  It's not as simple as downloading Windows 10

Comment: How to create an ISO from my laptop?

Comment: @SamC See duplicates answers

Comment: So, you can use Windows USB/DVD Download Tool, Rufus or other tool to create a bootable USB

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Your answer needs more detail. First, please read [answer], then [edit] your question to provide more detailed steps to carry out your solution.

Comment: @NDHien You mean directly from the installed OS?